# How do I specify the table from which a record should be deleted in Access using JOIN?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-delete, ms-access-2016

I have a table and a query, `qryAktuelleSchülerbilder`contains some of the records in `tblSchülerbilder`. My goal is to delete all records from `tblSchülerbilder` which do not exist in `qryAktuelleSchülerbilder`.
I can get those records with

```
SELECT tblSchülerbilder.*, qryAktuelleSchülerbilder.ID
FROM tblSchülerbilder
LEFT JOIN qryAktuelleSchülerbilder
ON tblSchülerbilder.ID = qryAktuelleSchülerbilder.ID
WHERE qryAktuelleSchülerbilder.ID Is Null;
```

When I now change over to a delete-query, the design-view in Access looks fine (I don't really know, what it does to the SQL-view at this point), it shows `tblSchülerbilder.*` with Delete: `From` and `ID` of `qryAktuelleSchülerbilder` with Delete: `Where` and Criteria: `Is Null`. But when I execute the query, it gives me `Specify the table containing the records you want to delete. (Error 3128)`.

I don't know where to put `tblSchülerbilder` again, since it is already set as delete from. The online article is of no help, since I have already specified `tblSchülerbilder.*` in the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `NOT IN`:

```
DELETE FROM tblSchülerbilder
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM qryAktuelleSchülerbilder)
```

or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM tblSchülerbilder AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM qryAktuelleSchülerbilder AS q
  WHERE q.ID = s.ID
)
```